# How do you enable MTP on Android 8.0.0?

Tags: file-transfer, usb-debugging, usb-connection-mode

Developer options on. Select USB Configuration is MTP (Media Transfer Protocol). When I plug the USB into my Windows 10 computer it does nothing.

Comment: First of all, I'd check if the USB cable is actually [a data cable, not a charging-only cable](https://www.focusestech.com/what-is-the-difference-between-a-usb-data-cable-and-a-charging-cable.html). Like, can other smartphones/devices be detected?

Comment: It had the charging icon while telling me that the usb cable was not connected so I already did switch out the cable to one that I know can handle data. Same thing. That's when I enabled developer options. Now if I do settings > "usb" I can pick between `Connected Devices` > `USB` (it's grayed out and says not connected even though it **is** connected) and `Select USB Configuration` under developer options, which when I go to that is a very long list of options but MTP is selected. But I still don't see the phone's file system in Windows Explorer.

Comment: Hmm, you didn't mention the phone model, but you'll probably also need to [install OEM USB drivers for Windows](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/oem-usb). The Select USB Configuration in the Developer Options doesn't seem to always work though, based on my experience.

Comment: I tried it, along with a third usb cable but once they told me to navigate to the usb driver folder in the android sdk I stopped going down the rabbit hole. These are pretty extreme lengths to go to to transfer files. I'm pretty sure it used to work on this phone (motorola e^5). I guess I'll try another way LOL.